# Javascript custom template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a custom template engine in javascript but I'm having trouble getting started as I cannot extract tokens using regex.
Here are the requirements:

1. Variables are defined like this: `$(variable)`
2. Functions: `$(name arg1 "this is arg2 but it contains whitespaces.")`
3. Function arguments can contain other variables `$(name $(variable) arg2)`

Both variables and functions will be rendered async. For example: Get the value for `$(variable)` from db then replace it.

This is not for rendering an html page but to simply replace a string entered by a user on the backend.

**Edit**

More information:
Suppose a user enters the following string:
`$(id $(lowercase John))`
On the backend application must do:

1. Convert "John" to lowercase.
2. Get the id for "john" from db.

This is only a simple example to demonstrate how this should work.

Are there any libraries that can help me achieve this? If not, any idea how to implement this?

**EDIT 2:**
I tried using [Mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) and I changed the delimiters to $(), however the function (section) tags do no satisfy the requirements. In Mustache, for functions I must do this: `$(#name) $(variable) "this is arg2 but it contains whitespaces."$(/name)` also it does not support async rendering.

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This question needs more focus. Take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Template literals do not work in this scenario. The strings that I'm looking to replace are entered by users and users will be following the specified requirements on how to define variables or functions.

Comment: Why specifically can't you extract tokens with Regex? It seems like `/\$\(.+\)/` would work just fine.

Comment: @MattF. That regex also matches the text between variables, unless I'm missing something: https://regex101.com/r/QByNVG/3

Comment: Yes, that was an oversimplified example. You'll most likely need an Abstract Syntax Tree parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers on this post are correct, however, I want to share exactly how I managed to implement this:

1. Create a recursive match function. I used [Steven Leviathan's article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-nested) to implement this.
2. Create a  render function and inside the function call the recursive match function to find and replace variable/function names with appropriate values.
3. Keep calling the render function recursively until all arguments inside a function have been replaced.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/MdswhC/1). This regex will identify the templates that can be replaced. Note that it only selects the innermost templates in nested templates.

```
/\$\((?<FirstTerm>\S+?)(?<OtherTerms>(?:\s+(?:\w+|".*?"))+)?\)/g
```

So just use a regex replace function with your templating logic recursively until there are no more matches. The inner templates will be replaced and you'll be left with the string with templates replaced.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Try it at https://regex101.com/r/jhRfp2/2—it doesn't select templates containing other templates. It's a nice try, but I've realized that a regex is the wrong approach.

Comment: @MattF. well no, I said it wouldn't. I'll improve my answer. 1 sec

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. In this case, I think this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, any idea how to implement this?

You should use an Abstract Syntax Tree, and write a compatible parser. While regex (as Pedro Lima stated) is good for simple templating, if you ever want to extend the parser, you'll need something a bit more robust.

As an example of an Abstract Syntax Tree parser, `$(test1 $(test2) test3) lorem ipsum $(test4)` would be turned into the following:

[image: Abstract Syntax Tree representation of the preceding statement. Branches: "Template", with children "test1", "Template", with children "test2", and "test3"; " lorem ipsum "; and "Template", with child "test4".]
(Thanks to Mile Shang's [Syntree](http://mshang.ca/syntree) for the tree generator.)

As for specifically how to write a parser, I think you can figure it out. Just iterate over the string and check for the template delimiter. Reading the source code for a templating library like Handlebars might help.